# How to suppress iteration output from Boosted tree model gbm in Caret from R studio

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

If I run this code tot train a gbm-model with Knitr, I receive several pages of Iter output like copied below. Is there a method to suppress this output?

```
mod_gbm <- train(classe ~ ., data = TrainSet, method = "gbm")


## Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
##      1        1.6094             nan     0.1000    0.1322
##      2        1.5210             nan     0.1000    0.0936
##      3        1.4608             nan     0.1000    0.0672
##      4        1.4165             nan     0.1000    0.0561
##      5        1.3793             nan     0.1000    0.0441
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried, `...method = "gbm", verbose = FALSE)`?

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Jason thanks, the verbose = FALSE suppress the output!

Comment: `verbose=F` should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `train` the argument `trace = FALSE`.

This is a parameter not defined in the `train` documentation explicitly as it is part of the `...` optional parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately "trace" is not recognized as a parameter as of caret v6.0-84